# MKReverseGeocoder and memory management?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I would like to ask about memory management with regards to `MKReverseGeocoder`, prior to iOS4.3 I had been using the code below, allocing `MKReverseGeocoder` and then releasing it in either `reverseGeocoder:didFindPlavemark` or `reverseGeoCoder:didFailWithError` as appropriate.

However with iOS4.3 I am getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` and it seems to be coming from the release in `reverseGeocoder:didFailWithError`. I would very much appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction, could I use autoRelease, would that alloc the geoCoder to hang around long enough for the delegate to do its work?

```
// ALLOC & START
MKReverseGeocoder *myGeocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:[lastGoodLocation coordinate]];
[myGeocoder setDelegate:self];
[myGeocoder start];
```

.

```
// DID FIND
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark {
    NSLog(@"GEOCODE: didFindPlacemark");
    [self createLocation:placemark];
    [geocoder release];
}
```

.

```
// DID FAIL
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"GEOCODE: didFailWithError");
    [self createLocation:nil];
    [geocoder release];
}
```

Comment: I totally would've suggested what you ended up doing. And I also agree that it feels a bit messay to release in those delegate methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a little searching, I think the solution might be to setup an iVar to hold the MKReverseGeocoder. This way I can use autorelease whilst still being sure that the iVar will hold onto the geoCoder until the next time the iVar is set. Interestingly enough the code above only produces an EXC_BAD_ACCESS from `reverseGeocoder:didFailWithError`, not from `reverseGeocoder:didFindPlacemark`. I also checked the retain counts (yes I know its not reliable but I wanted to look) and before the release (that crashes) both methods report a retain count of 1. The only thing I can guess is that the geocoded object might still be being used somewhere when I do the release. It also feels messy allocing in one method and releasing using a pointer from the callback.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain)MKReverseGeocoder geoCoder;
```

.

```
[self setGeoCoder:[[[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord] autorelease]];
[[self geoCoder] setDelegate:self];
[[self geoCoder] start];
```

Comment: I am assuming that from the lack of answers and the comment from @donkey that this is indeed the correct way to manage instances of MKReverseGeocoder.

Comment: I ran into the same problem myself. Turning on some memory debugging flags it is indeed MKReverseGeocoder that continues to send messages after being released: *** -[MKReverseGeocoder requesterDidCancel:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6647360. I solved it myself by autoreleasing instead of releasing